# Can we find any (better) pairing function $f(x,y)$ with $f(0,y)=0$? Does it help if we do know min/max values of $x,y$?

Tags: functions, computer-science

I'm looking for a pairing function $f(x,y)$ which gives unique values for every combination of integers $x,y>0$ and and as special property 0 for $x=0$ $\forall y$.
Or to be more general we can also replace $0$ with constants.

- We do know the max values of $x$ and $y$ can achieve
- We are allowed to shift $x, y$ values. So we also know their min values. Which don't need to be 0 
  So the more general definitions with constants $c_x, c_f$ (instead of $0$):
  $$ x_{min} \le x \le x_{max}$$
  $$ y_{min} \le y \le y_{max}$$
  $$\forall y: f(c_x,y) = c_f $$
  $$\forall y, \forall x\not= c_x: f(x,y)\not = f(y,x) \not = c_f$$
- It will be used in a computer program. The goal is finding a function with a max result as small as possible (bit's needed for representation) while still being easy and fast to compute by a machine (not using too much storage). Therefore integer calculations are appreciated. Floating point can lead to  inaccuracies.
- The inverse can be anything. We only need to check if two variables $x,y$ lead to the target number.
- No case selections are allowed (e.g. for $x=0$). Something like Kronecker Delta function which can only be $0$ for input $0$ and $1$ for anything else is also not allowed.

Target value size, the number of different values $|${$x$}$|$ $= 2^{16} = 65536$ and
$|${$y$}$|$ at least $2^{26} = 67108864$. 
Size $|${$y$}$|$ can be bigger but $\max f(x,y) < 2^{92}$

Can we find any such function?

---

Here some **Examples:**

**I**) Pairing functions which **do not work**  ( not $0$ or a constant for any $x = c_x$ ) :
Cantor's pairing function :
$$f(x,y)=\frac{(x+y)\cdot (x+y+1)}{2} + a$$
Szudzik pairing function:

$$
\begin{eqnarray*} 
f(x,y) = 
\begin{cases} 
y^2 + x, &\text{if }x < y,
\\ y^2 + x + y, &\text{if }x \ge y
\end{cases}
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
This has some cases selection we do not want. We can shift $y$ to be always larger than $x$ and with this reduce it to:
$$f(x,y) = (y+x_{max} +1 )^2 + x$$
Can we modify them to be a constant for a certain $x = c_x$?

---

**II**)
Pairing function which **does work** but needs extra memory/time : 
If we use $0 \le x \le 2^{16}-1$ it can not surpass value $2^{16} = 65536$. Next prime above it is 65537. This is the 6543'th prime number. 
Let $p(i)$ return the $i'th$ prime number.
Let $0 \le y \le 2^{26}-1$ 
With this we can do the pairing function:
$$f(x,y) = x \cdot p(y + 6543)$$
This returns a unique value for every combination $x,y$ except for $x = c_x = 0$ it will always return the constant $c_f = 0$.
However this works good in theory but calculating $p$ takes quite a long time. Storing all values would take a lot of memory ($\approx 268$ MB) - not a nice option. 
Max value of $f(x,y)$ would be $2^{46.31}$ needing $47$ bits which is not too far from optimum $42$ bits. (Cantor  and Szudzik are much bigger)

To reduce memory we can split $y$ into half bit-size parts. For $2^{26}$ different values this would be $2^{13}$. First part gets represented by the first $2^{13}$ primes after $2^{16}$, second part by the $2^{13}$ primes after that.
$$f(x,y) = x \cdot p(y_{\text{bits } 1..13} + 6543) \cdot p(y_{\text{bits } 14..26} + 6543 + 2^{13}) $$
This would reduce memory but scales the max value of $f(x,y)$ to $2^{51.3}$, so we need $52$ bits.

---

**Question:** Can we find any such pairing function which does not need to replace parameter $x,y$ with their primes (or similar) while the resulting value $f(x,y)$ won't get much bigger than $2^{52}$ (at most $2^{92}-1$ ) ?

---

**III**) Pairing function which **might work** but is **too big**:
While testing around I came up with 
$$f(x,y) = ((x+1)^2+y^2) \cdot (x^3+(y+1)^2) \cdot x$$
I have **no proof** that this is a valid pairing function for all combinations $x,y$ but in tests it did work for all combinations $x<2^{8}, y<2^{20}$
However the results can get too big. It needs up to $121$ bits. 
Can we find a pairing function with a smaller max value?

---

Edit:
**IV**) For $0\ge x < 2^{m}$, $0\ge y < 2^{n}$ we could do
$$ f(x,y) = 2^{m}\cdot x \cdot y + x$$
With target $m=16, n=24$ this will give us $58$ bit numbers.
Can we go smaller?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? And if you know that $0\leq x,y<2^n$ then why not just take $f(x,y)=x+2^ny$?

Comment: @Servaes I want to use it in a computer application for some sort of encryption which needs at least one inverse ($c_x$ ,$f_x$) while the others need to be hard to find to avoid breaking it (related [thread](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/111216/can-we-make-a-cipher-chain-with-aes-hard-to-invert-for-all-except-one-chosen) there). This restricts the total size to 128-bits (- some for some other usage, 92 bit remain). It could be longer but with this would take much more computation time. Goal is to make it efficient.

Comment: @Servaes For $f(x,y) = x + 2^n \cdot y$ we don't have this special case for a constant $c_x$ being a constant result $c_f$ $\forall y$. The goal is finding 1 way easy but avoid finding a specific one. In encryption we start at a certain number $c$ use $x$ as key but extend it with a variable related to the number $f_y(y)$  to get the final encryption key $f(x,f_y(c) )$. As result we get a new number. We repeat this encryption with different keys multiple times and end in a final number....

Comment: ... The user will get assigned such a final number and want to find the keys needed leading to another users number. Therefore he first needs to go backwards. The special case $c_x$ makes this easy. The goal is to let them try as many as possible key combinations in forward direction. If the inverse is easy to compute they can just both compute many ancestors and with this find a connection much faster

Comment: But for $0\ge x<2^{16},0\ge y<2^{26}$
 we could do $2^{16} \cdot x \cdot y+x$
. This will give us 58 bit numbers. Can we go smaller? (will add it on top. Thanks for the hint!)

Comment: I recall that Kronecker Delta function can be implemented without case selection. Namely, let $z$ be any nonnegative integer number and $p$ be any prime which does not divide $z$ (for instance, because $z<p$). Then by Fermat's little theorem, the canonical residue of $z^{p-1}$ modulo $p$ equals $0$, if $z=0$, and equals $1$, otherwise.

Comment: Moreover if $p=2^n+1$ is a Fermat prime (for instance, as $2^{16}+1=65537$), then $p-1=2^{2^n}$ and the canonical residue of $z^{2^k}$ modulo $p$ can be rather quickly calculated by induction on $k$, putting $z_0$ be the canonical residue of $z^{2^0}$ modulo $p$, and for each natural $k\le n$ $z_k$ be the canonical residue of $z_{k-1}^2$ modulo $p$

Comment: Also the Kronecker Delta function can be implemented if there is a function $p(i)$ which returns the $i$′th prime number for a natural $i$. Namely, the canonical residue modulo $2$ of $p(z+1)$ equals $0$, if $z=0$, and equals $1$, otherwise.

Comment: In Approach II we can try to split $y$ into more parts. Maybe we can try to split $x$ similarly.

Comment: @AlexRavsky not entirely sure how $f(x,y)$ would look like using the $z_{k-1}^2 \mod  p$ approach but for others it introduces just a Kronecker Delta like function with it's only purpose being is a case selection. This should be avoided. Replacing it with a normal case selection would be faster. For  approach II) I tried splitting $y$ in smaller and not equal sized bit parts. Only got larger results. Splitting $x$ would result in replacing it with primes as well. Doing this we lose the property for $x=0$. We could replace it with $0$ but this wouldn't be a very elegant solution.